# How to give poi table margin from left word document

Tags: apache-poi

I am creating a word document using POI. I have created a table and a header. I want to give left margin to table so I used this code:

```
CTSectPr getSectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
CTPageMar addNewPgMar = getSectPr.addNewPgMar();
addNewPgMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(200));
addNewPgMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(200));
addNewPgMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
addNewPgMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

But this code also give 200 margin to header from left. I Want only for table.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your code creates page margins. From your description it is not really clear what you are tying to achieve. Please show the wanted result.

Comment: Want to give margin only  word document table but header also takes margin which i dont want..how to give margin only word document components not header and footer.

Answer (score 3):

The page margins, you set using the code shown, are margins for the whole page. Headers and footers also are part of the page as well as the body. The additional settings `setFooter` and `setHeader` in page margins are settings for distances of the header from top and the footer from bottom of the page. There are no special settings to set left distance only for body or header/footer. So changed left page margins also affect the header and footer.

All you could do is set additional indentations for paragraphs and tables in the body.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageMar;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // set indentation of the paragraph
  paragraph.setIndentationLeft(720); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // set indentation of the paragraph
  paragraph.setIndentationLeft(720);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 1");

  // create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
  // set indentation of the table
  CTTblWidth tableIndentation = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblInd();
  tableIndentation.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  tableIndentation.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  // set indentation of the paragraph
  paragraph.setIndentationLeft(720);

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = document.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Footer");

  // create page margins
  CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.getPgMar();
  if (pageMar == null) pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(720));
  pageMar.setGutter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooter.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

This code is tested using `apache poi 4.1.0` and needs the the full `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).