# Need to shift the table to right in apache poi word

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I have created the table in apache POI, need to create another similar table but shifted right:
[image: Created table with Apache POI]

But I want to create similar another table to the right but at bottom.
[image]

Do we have a setting in XWPFTable to set the alignment for the table to shift right or Do i need to re-build the entire table again

### Code snippet

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The table:");
        createNonGroupedSubTacTable(document);
        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
        if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
        pageSz.setOrient(STPageOrientation.PORTRAIT);
        pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(11900)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
        pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(16840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example_docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
    }

    private static void createNonGroupedSubTacTable(XWPFDocument document) {
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable(10, 8);
        setTableAlign(table);
        int defaultColWidth = 1 * 1600 * 5 / 8; // 8 columns fits to 8 inches
        int[] colunmWidths = new int[]{
                defaultColWidth * 3 / 4, defaultColWidth * 8 / 4, defaultColWidth * 2 / 4, defaultColWidth * 3 / 4,
                defaultColWidth * 3 / 4, defaultColWidth * 2 / 4, defaultColWidth * 8 / 4, defaultColWidth * 3 / 4
        };
        table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[0]));
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
        //other columns
        for (int col = 1; col < colunmWidths.length; col++) {
            table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[col]));
            setColumnWidth(table, 0, col, colunmWidths[col]);
        }
        //set cell borders
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL});
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(4), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        }
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK});
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(4), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        }
        table.getRow(0).setHeight(28 * 20); // 28pt row height
        table.getRow(0).getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);

        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(7);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Species:");
        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(6);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Greater silver smelt");

        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(3);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Zone:");

        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(1);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Union and international waters of 1 and 2 (2)");

        table.getRow(1).setHeight(28 * 20); // 28pt row height
        table.getRow(1).getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);

        cell = table.getRow(1).getCell(6);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.addBreak();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Argentinia silos");

        cell = table.getRow(1).getCell(1);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.addTab();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.addTab();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.addBreak();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("(ARU/1/2)");
        for (int row = 2; row < 6; row++) {
            for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(5), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(6), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }

            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(7);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setFontSize(10);
            run.setText("Belgium");

            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(6);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("6  ");
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("(2)");
            run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2)
        }

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 2, 0, 3);
        cell = table.getRow(2).getCell(0);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Analytical TAC");

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 3, 0, 3);
        cell = table.getRow(3).getCell(0);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Article 3 of Regulation (EC) No 847/96 shall not apply");

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 4, 0, 3);
        cell = table.getRow(4).getCell(0);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(10);
        run.setText("Article 4 of Regulation (EC) No 847/96 shall not apply.");

        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(6).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }

        for (int row = 7; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(4), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }

            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(7);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("TAC");

            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(6);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("10");
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("(2)");
            run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2)
        }
        for (int row = 8; row < 10; row++) {
            if (row == 9) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
                }
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(5), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
                for (int col = 4; col < 8; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
                }
            } else {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
                }
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(5), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
                for (int col = 4; col < 8; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
                }

            }
            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(7);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("1");


            mergeCellHorizontally(table, row, 0, 5);
            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(0);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setFontSize(9);
            run.setText("Up to 2 % of the quota may consist of by-catches of whiting and mackerel (OT1/*2A3A4). " +
                    "By-catches of whiting and mackerel counted against the quota pursuant to this provision and by-catches of species counted " +
                    "against the quota pursuant to Article 15(8) of Regulation (EU) No 1380/2013 shall, together, not exceed 9% of the quota.");

        }

    }

    private static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
        CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
        tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
        tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr != null) {
            tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
        } else {
            tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
            tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
            table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
        }
    }

    private static void setCellBorders(XWPFTableCell cell, STBorder.Enum[] borderTypesLTRB) {
        CTTcBorders borders = CTTcBorders.Factory.newInstance();
        borders.addNewLeft().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[0]);
        borders.addNewTop().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[1]);
        borders.addNewRight().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[2]);
        borders.addNewBottom().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[3]);
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr != null) {
            tcPr.setTcBorders(borders);
        } else {
            tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
            tcPr.setTcBorders(borders);
            cell.getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
        }
    }

    private static void mergeCellHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int row, int fromCol, int toCol) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(fromCol);
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        if (tcPr.isSetGridSpan()) {
            tcPr.getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol - fromCol + 1));
        } else {
            tcPr.addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol - fromCol + 1));
        }
        for (int colIndex = toCol; colIndex > fromCol; colIndex--) {
            table.getRow(row).getCtRow().removeTc(colIndex);
            table.getRow(row).removeCell(colIndex);
        }
    }

    private static void setTableAlign(XWPFTable table) {
        CTTbl cttblp = table.getCTTbl();
        CTTblPr cttblpr;
        cttblpr = (cttblp.getTblPr() == null ? cttblp.addNewTblPr() : cttblp.getTblPr());
        cttblpr.addNewBidiVisual().setVal(STOnOff.ON);
        CTJc ctjc = (cttblpr.isSetJc() ? cttblpr.getJc() : cttblpr.addNewJc());
        ctjc.setVal(STJc.LEFT);
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307564/how-to-give-poi-table-margin-from-left-word-document/57315445#57315445. There also is [XWPFTable.setTableAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#setTableAlignment-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.TableRowAlign-),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indent the table using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
// set indentation of the table
CTTblWidth tableIndentation = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblInd();
tableIndentation.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
tableIndentation.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
```

But there also is [XWPFTable.setTableAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#setTableAlignment-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.TableRowAlign-). Using that you can align the whole table.

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
table.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.RIGHT); //table right aligned
```

For `apache poi` versions prior `4.1.1` the following low level approach can be used to right align the table:

```
XWPFTable  table = document.createTable(3,3);
table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewJc().setVal(STJc.RIGHT);  //table right aligned
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTableIndent {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table indented:");
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(3,3);
  // set indentation of the table
  CTTblWidth tableIndentation = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblInd();
  tableIndentation.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(720)); //720 TWentieths of an Inch Point (Twips) = 720/20 = 36 pt = 36/72 = 0.5"
  tableIndentation.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
  }
  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1440+1440/8));
  //other columns
  for (int col = 1; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1440+1440/8));
  }
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table right aligned:");
  table = document.createTable(3,3);
  table.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.RIGHT); //table right aligned
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    table.getRow(row).getCell(col).setText("row " + row + ", col " + col);
   }
  }
  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1440+1440/8));
  //other columns
  for (int col = 1; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(1440+1440/8));
  }
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();


  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableIndent.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this approach is only possible with apache -poi 4.1.0 but i am using the following dependency : <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>  <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version> <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>  And i cannot upgrade as my project is also using jasper which internally using xmlbeans for higher version

Comment: @Neha Mishra: To indent the table using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes is possible using your versions too. Only `XWPFTable.setTableAlignment` needs `apache poi 4.1.1`.

Comment: @Neha Mishra: For `apache poi` versions prior `4.1.1` the following low level approach can be used to right align the table: `XWPFTable  table = document.createTable(3,3); table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewJc().setVal(STJc.RIGHT);  //table right aligned`.

Comment: Added the below 2 lines and the issue appear after mergeCellHorizontally and the table regain to original size

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about your problems with your provided complete example:

First: Aligning by using bidirectional text settings so table is displayed in a right to left direction is not to recommend. This only should be used for langauges which really needs bidirectional text, hebrew or arabic for example. So your table aligning rather should be like:

```
private static void setTableAlign(XWPFTable table, STJc.Enum align) {
    CTTbl cttblp = table.getCTTbl();
    CTTblPr cttblpr = (cttblp.getTblPr() == null ? cttblp.addNewTblPr() : cttblp.getTblPr());
    CTJc ctjc = (cttblpr.isSetJc() ? cttblpr.getJc() : cttblpr.addNewJc());
    ctjc.setVal(align);
}
```

Second: When cells were merged, then the column width for the new merged cell should be set. Else `Word` will possibly use kinds of unwanted automatism to determine column widths. So for example:

```
...
mergeCellHorizontally(table, 2, 4, 7);
setColumnWidth(table, 2, 4, colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);
...
```

and

```
...
mergeCellHorizontally(table, row, 1, 7);
setColumnWidth(table, row, 1, colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);
...
```

Complete example for creating a right aligned table as of your provided screen shots:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The table:");
        createNonGroupedSubTacTable(document);
        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
        if (sectPr == null) sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
        pageSz.setOrient(STPageOrientation.PORTRAIT);
        pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(11900)); //12240 Twips = 12240/20 = 612 pt = 612/72 = 8.5"
        pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(16840)); //15840 Twips = 15840/20 = 792 pt = 792/72 = 11"

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();
    }

    private static void createNonGroupedSubTacTable(XWPFDocument document) {
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable(10, 8);

        setTableAlign(table, STJc.RIGHT);

        int defaultColWidth = 1 * 1600 * 5 / 8; // 8 columns fits to 8 inches
        int[] colunmWidths = new int[]{
                defaultColWidth * 3 / 4, defaultColWidth * 2 / 4, defaultColWidth * 8 / 4, defaultColWidth * 3 / 4,
                defaultColWidth * 3 / 4, defaultColWidth * 2 / 4, defaultColWidth * 8 / 4, defaultColWidth * 3 / 4
        };
        table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[0]));
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, colunmWidths[0]);
        //other columns
        for (int col = 1; col < colunmWidths.length; col++) {
            table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colunmWidths[col]));
            setColumnWidth(table, 0, col, colunmWidths[col]);
        }
        //set cell borders
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL});
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(4), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(0).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        }
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(3), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK, STBorder.THICK});
        setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(4), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.THICK, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(1).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
        }
        table.getRow(0).setHeight(28 * 20); // 28pt row height
        table.getRow(0).getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);

        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(0);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Species:");
        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(2);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Greater silver smelt");

        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(4);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Zone:");

        cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(6);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Union and international waters of 1 and 2 (2)");

        table.getRow(1).setHeight(28 * 20); // 28pt row height
        table.getRow(1).getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);

        cell = table.getRow(1).getCell(2);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.addBreak();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("Argentinia silos");

        cell = table.getRow(1).getCell(6);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.addTab();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.addTab();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.addBreak();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("(ARU/1/2)");

        for (int row = 2; row < 6; row++) {
            for (int col = 5; col < 8; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(5), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(6), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }

            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(0);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setFontSize(10);
            run.setText("Belgium");

            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(3);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            //paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("6  ");
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("(2)");
            run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2)
        }

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 2, 4, 7);
        setColumnWidth(table, 2, 4, colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);
        cell = table.getRow(2).getCell(4);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20);
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Analytical TAC");

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 3, 4, 7);
        setColumnWidth(table, 3, 4, colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);
        cell = table.getRow(3).getCell(4);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Article 3 of Regulation (EC) No 847/96 shall not apply");

        mergeCellHorizontally(table, 4, 4, 7);
        setColumnWidth(table, 4, 4, colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);
        cell = table.getRow(4).getCell(4);
        paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
        paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
        run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
        run.setFontSize(9);
        run.setText("Article 4 of Regulation (EC) No 847/96 shall not apply.");

        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            setCellBorders(table.getRow(6).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
        }

        for (int row = 7; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
            }

            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(0);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("TAC");

            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(3);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            //paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("10");
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("(2)");
            run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT); // superscript (2)
        }


        for (int row = 8; row < 10; row++) {
            if (row == 9) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.THICK});
                }
            } else {
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                    setCellBorders(table.getRow(row).getCell(col), new STBorder.Enum[]{STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL, STBorder.NIL});
                }
            }

            XWPFTableCell cell1 = table.getRow(row).getCell(0);
            paragraph = (cell1.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell1.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell1.addParagraph();
            paragraph.setIndentationLeft(5 * 20); // 10pt left indentation
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run.setText("1");


            mergeCellHorizontally(table, row, 1, 7);
            setColumnWidth(table, row, 1, colunmWidths[1]+colunmWidths[2]+colunmWidths[3]+colunmWidths[4]+colunmWidths[5]+colunmWidths[6]+colunmWidths[7]);

            cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(1);
            paragraph = (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) ? cell.getParagraphs().get(0) : cell.addParagraph();
            run = (paragraph.getRuns().size() > 0) ? paragraph.getRuns().get(0) : paragraph.createRun();
            run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setFontSize(9);
            run.setText("Up to 2 % of the quota may consist of by-catches of whiting and mackerel (OT1/*2A3A4). " +
                    "By-catches of whiting and mackerel counted against the quota pursuant to this provision and by-catches of species counted " +
                    "against the quota pursuant to Article 15(8) of Regulation (EU) No 1380/2013 shall, together, not exceed 9% of the quota.");
        }

    }

    private static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
        CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
        tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
        tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
        CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr != null) {
            tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
        } else {
            tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
            tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
            table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
        }
    }

    private static void setCellBorders(XWPFTableCell cell, STBorder.Enum[] borderTypesLTRB) {
        CTTcBorders borders = CTTcBorders.Factory.newInstance();
        borders.addNewLeft().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[0]);
        borders.addNewTop().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[1]);
        borders.addNewRight().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[2]);
        borders.addNewBottom().setVal(borderTypesLTRB[3]);
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr != null) {
            tcPr.setTcBorders(borders);
        } else {
            tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
            tcPr.setTcBorders(borders);
            cell.getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
        }
    }

    private static void mergeCellHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int row, int fromCol, int toCol) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(fromCol);
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        if (tcPr.isSetGridSpan()) {
            tcPr.getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol - fromCol + 1));
        } else {
            tcPr.addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol - fromCol + 1));
        }
        for (int colIndex = toCol; colIndex > fromCol; colIndex--) {
            table.getRow(row).getCtRow().removeTc(colIndex);
            table.getRow(row).removeCell(colIndex);
        }
    }

    private static void setTableAlign(XWPFTable table, STJc.Enum align) {
        CTTbl cttblp = table.getCTTbl();
        CTTblPr cttblpr = (cttblp.getTblPr() == null ? cttblp.addNewTblPr() : cttblp.getTblPr());
        CTJc ctjc = (cttblpr.isSetJc() ? cttblpr.getJc() : cttblpr.addNewJc());
        ctjc.setVal(align);
    }
}
```